# Frequency vs total count bar plot in python

Tags: python, plot

I have a datafram with following structure

```
,mphA,gyrA,parC,tet59,qnrVC
sample1,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
sample2,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
sample3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
sample4,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
sample5,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
sample6,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
sample7,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
sample8,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE
sample9,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
sample10,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
```

And I need to generate a frequency vs total count bar plot similar to the following figure in python. Its a combination of 3 plots so I guess you need to plot them independently and put them in a single canvas. I frequently see this plot in journals so I guess it should be implemented already. However, I did not have any success with online search. Does anybody know how it can be done? Thanks.[image]

Comment: That it is frequently used in publications does not mean there is a freely available library for it. Could be part of proprietary software of a sequencing device/analysis tool. I cannot remember having seen the central diagram before. I would not even know what the name for it is. And still: Just asking for a library is not a valid question on SO. But what do these publications say they used to generate the graphs?

Comment: @Mr.T. You are right. Unfortunately, papers do not discuss about these details. I am actually asking for a way to do it, not specifically for a library. But anyway, if you still think this question is not a valid question on stackoverflow, I will delete it?!

Comment: I actually like the question. Maybe some coding attempt from your side, so we can work together on it? I would also like to know what the name of this graph in the center is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done easily using UpSetPlot

https://pypi.org/project/UpSetPlot/